# Make WPF Interface Free of display size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ok, so I'm developing a C# WPF Application. The MainWindow for this app is always fullscreen, but I need to adjust the controls based on resolution. Anyway, I have tried quite a few things to achieve this. Right now, I have set the Grid length & width to `Auto`. The problem is that my controls shift up and to the left for some reason. Below is my MainWindowXAML. (BTW: The window contains: Image buttons, Labels, Rectangles, and TextBoxes):

```
<Window x:Name="Menu" x:Class="App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="App1" FontWeight="Bold"  Icon="Images/Core-IconSize.ico" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Height="870" Width="1388">

    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     //Controls here.  
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

Edit: Added XAML for controls.

Comment: You should add the XAML with all controls so we can comment on the issue.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma Ok I'll add it...

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma added it.

Comment: When do the components go up and left? Is it when you increase resolution, or decrease it?

Comment: @Ethan_Cabiac I'm not doing either. I keep my resolution but I'm trying to make it so that it supports different resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your controls to scale up or down if the screen size is different; rather than just shift positions.

If this is what you want, you can achieve this effect by putting your `Grid` inside a `Viewbox` control.  The `Viewbox` will then automatically scale it's contents up or down to fit the existing real estate.

Also, you may want to remove the height and width properties from your window as they are redundant for a full-screen application.  If you want a specific size while you are editing the window in XAML, you can set the designheight and designwidth properties.

Example **without** the `Viewbox`:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Exploration.Windows.wndDataGrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="wndDataGrid" Height="300" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Load Text File" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="10" Click="LoadTextFile"/>
            <Button Content="Save Text File" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="10" Click="SaveTextFile"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Some content here"/>
        <Button Content="Another Button" Grid.Row="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Example **with** the `Viewbox`:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Exploration.Windows.wndDataGrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="wndDataGrid" Height="300" Width="500">
    <Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="200" Height="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Load Text File" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="10" Click="LoadTextFile"/>
            <Button Content="Save Text File" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="10" Click="SaveTextFile"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Some content here"/>
        <Button Content="Another Button" Grid.Row="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

[image]

Depending on how your grid and it's contents are set up, you may not need to give the actual grid a defined size.

Comment: You may have to play around with your grid size and your grid row and column settings for this to work well.  By default, a grid is an auto-sized object, so putting it inside a viewbox will not produce good results unless you give your grid a fixed size.  Then the viewbox has something to work with for scaling.

Comment: I'm actually pretty much clueless as to how to do this, sorry.

Comment: This seems to work well. Do you know why the text would shrink so much on a 1680X1050 screen?

Comment: Not off-hand, no.  But, you've got a lot of extra properties set on all the objects in your XAML.  I'm guessing you used the designer to drag-and-drop.  This works well to start, but VS sets a lot of extra properties that may have unintended consequences later.